# Trying to avoid combining .pack() and .grid() using tkinter and struggling. Which option is better and why?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been working on a developing a GUI using Python, Tkinter and Pillow (simple UI for a work application I am working on). I consistently run into an issue about the geometry manager running into issues because you 'cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack'.

This issues **only happens** when I add my `class page_Roster` to the application. I am not sure what I am doing run, but I suspect I must have goofed something up with the `__init__` declaration or instantiation. Any help appreciated, but certainly chief among my concerns is figuring out how to work with which geometry manager in tkinter and when/why!

```
import tkinter as tk                
from tkinter import font  as tkfont 
from tkinter import *
import importlib

from PIL import *
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk

class BellBankLMS(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)


        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=14, weight="bold", slant="italic")

        self.title('Bell Bank: Learning Management Software')
        self.geometry("450x450")
        self.resizable(0, 0)


        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


        self.frames = {}
        for F in (page_Menu, page_Training, page_Quizzes, page_Mgmt, page_Roster):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

            self.show_frame("page_Menu")

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            # frame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class page_Menu(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller


        ### This code is not working currently // It displays Bell Bank logo

        # BellLogo = Image.open('bell1.png')
        # BellLogo = BellLogo.resize((85, 85), Image.ANTIALIAS)

        # renderedLogo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(BellLogo)
        # LogoLabel = tk.Label(image=renderedLogo)
        # LogoLabel.pack()


        label = tk.Label(self, text="Bell Bank: Learning Management Software", font=controller.title_font, background="blue", foreground="white")
        label.pack(side="top")

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Training",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("page_Training"))
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Quizzes",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("page_Quizzes"))
        button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Management",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("page_Mgmt"))
        button1.pack(expand=1)
        button2.pack(expand=1)
        button3.pack(expand=1)


class page_Training(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Training To-Do, Scheduling, etc.", foreground="blue", background="lightgray")
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("page_Menu"))
        button.pack()


class page_Quizzes(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Quiz Scores, Performance, etc.", foreground="blue", background="lightgray")
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("page_Menu"))
        button.pack()


class page_Mgmt(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Trainer Admin: Course, Roster and Training Mgmt", foreground="blue", background="lightgray")
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("page_Menu"))
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Training Classes/Rosters", 
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("page_Roster"))
        button.pack()
        button1.pack()


class page_Roster(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        tasks=None

        super().__init__()

        if not tasks:
            self.tasks = []
        else:
            self.tasks = tasks

        trainee1 = tk.Label(self, text="---Add Trainee Here---", bg="lightgrey", fg="blue", pady=10)

        self.tasks.append(trainee1)

        for task in self.tasks:
            task.pack(side="top", fill="x")

        self.task_create = tk.Text(self, height=3, bg="white", fg="black")

        self.task_create.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
        self.task_create.focus_set()

        self.bind("<Return>", self.add_task)

        self.color_schemes = [{"bg": "lightgrey", "fg": "blue"}, {"bg": "grey", "fg": "white"}]


    def add_task(self, event=None):
        task_text = self.task_create.get(1.0,END).strip()

        if len(task_text) > 0:
            new_task = tk.Label(self, text=task_text, pady=10)

            _, task_style_choice = divmod(len(self.tasks), 2)

            my_scheme_choice = self.color_schemes[task_style_choice]

            new_task_configure(bg=my_scheme_choice["bg"])
            new_task_configure(fg=my_scheme_choice["fg"])

            new_task.pack(side="top", fill="x")

            self.tasks.append(new_task)

        self.task_create.delete(1.0, END)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = BellBankLMS()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: `page_Roster.__init__()` contains both `tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)` and `super().__init__()`, which are trying to do the same thing - incorrectly, in the second case, because you didn't include the `parent` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this code:

```
class page_Roster(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        tasks=None

        super().__init__()
```

Notice that you are first doing `tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)`, which calls the `__init__` of the superclass. A couple lines later you do `super().__init__()` which *also* calls the `__init__` of the superclass. Only, in this second attempt you are not passing `parent` to the function. Because of that, this widget is a child of the root window.

You need to do one of the following:

- remove the line `super().__init__()`, or
- remove the line `tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)` and change the other line to `super().__init__(parent)`.